# Mots du dictionnaire par contrainte

Tags: vocabulaire, lexique

Existe-il un logiciel ou un site web qui permet de trouver des mots à partir de contraintes tels que:

- Une seule sorte de voyelle. (ex: 'bal')
- Une seule syllabe (exemple: 'bol')
- Longueur maximale
  etc.

Le but étant de trouver efficacement des mots simples pour des exercices de lecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il en existe même des tas sur le net ! Des recherches de quelques minutes avec les mots-clefs "générateur de mots" vous donneront énormément de sites qui font tout cela ! Et si vous voulez des contraintes vous pouvez ajouter cette contrainte. Par exemple "générateur de mots commençant par".

[Ce générateur](http://generateurmots.chez.com/) permet de générer des mots avec une contrainte de nombre de syllabes (min et max).

[Cet autre générateur](http://www.dcode.fr/mots-commencant-par) permet de générer des mots qui commencent par une contrainte et vous pouvez même spécifier des lettres (donc également des syllabes) de départ. Vous pouvez également y spécifier le nombre de lettres maximal !

Le site "dcode" est un outil qui, je pense, vous sera très utile dans ce genre de recherches. Il contient énormément d'outils et de ressources pour les personnes qui jouent avec la langue !

Answer (score 2):

Ce n'est pas exactement ce que vous demandez, mais le CD-ROM *Petit Robert* propose « recherche par critères » :

- groupes de lettres (avec jokers : un caractère, une voyelle, une consonne)
- catégorie grammaticale
- transcription phonétique

Donc, on peut chercher par exemple un mot avec une consonne - une voyelle - une consonne pour obtenir la liste *bac, bah, bal, ban, bar, bas* etc.

Et on peut également chercher une consonne - la lettre e - une consonne pour voir *bec, bel, ben, ber, cep* etc.